# Add aggregated permissions from AD in token

Tags: active-directory, keycloak

We use Keycloak to federate AD authentication/authorization for applications.
We have AD groups per application and control access by managing membership of these groups.

- App1 - Admin, Basic, Manager
- App2 - Admin, Operator, Support

We add user AD groups in to the token as custom claim, so that applications then know which user with which group has signed in.

Now for some realms, we need to control permissions for these groups from AD. For example: In AD we can define that Operator group has "p1, p2, p3..." permissions and instead of groups, we will add permissions in the token.

How can we do this? is it possible? what is the best practice?